# Git не разрешает переключиться на главную ветку

Tags: git, git-branch

Суть проблемы такова:

У меня есть репозиторий который я использую как точку отсчета для любого проекта. Назовём его условно `start-pack`

В зависимости от того, какой будет проект я клонирую определенную ветку этого репозитория.

Я склонировал ветку `html-storage` из  репозитория `start-pack` на компьютер, а после поменял url репозитория проекта в локальной машине, на тот, что только что создал под новый проект командой.

```
git remote set-url origin "github.com/my-new-rep"
```

Автоматически в этом репозитории, как локальном так и удаленном создалась ветка на которой я находился изначально т.е. `html-storage`

Главная проблема: я не могу запушить в main ветку, хотя она пустая.  Git ругается, что голова позади и мол попробуйте спулить изменения, но я пробовал разные манипуляции, ничего не помогло.

Я бы мог конечно изменить всё с флагом `--force`, но мне хотелось бы понимать, как правильно поступать в такой ситуации.

Comment: *"Git ругается, что голова позади"* - это означает, что в утверждении *"хотя она пустая"* содержится ошибка. Конкретики в вопросе нехватает.

Comment: Может просто main защищен от прямых пушей и надо PR делать?

Comment: Попробовал отдельно склонировать ветку `html-storage` с нового репозитория. Сделал изменения мелкие для теста. Пробую git push -u origin main и вот что выдаёт:
src refspec main ничему не соответствует